# How to declare that a var has now been initialized, if Flow can't infer it automatically?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Try [this code in Flow's REPL](https://flowtype.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBGCuBbARgUwE4RgXhgbQEYAaGAJhIGYSAWEgVgF0BuAKBYBtVZEBDADwBccJGnSsWCFBggA6AGYh0AUR7AAFgAoAllFSIcAPhgBvFjBha5MDQEJefGAB9HF3fqP2AlDHs5Xe1gBfT3FQSBBOGXYQAHMNewBqBJCYAHpUmCgATwAHVBgMdEUWIA):

```
const numbers = [5, 3, 22, 2, 6];

let max: number;

numbers.forEach(item => {
  if (!max || item > max) max = item;
});

console.log(max++); // type error
```

I can be certain that `max` will have been initialized as a number before the `max++` expression. But Flow can't infer this automatically, so it complains.

I want to say to Flow, after the forEach: please assume the `max` variable has now been initialized. Is there a way to do this?

(Related – Flow has 'declarations': `declare var max: number;` – this lets you declare that a number variable called `var` exists in global scope. But you can't use it to redeclare something already declared in your own scope.)

Comment: this behavior makes kinda sense - there's no *compile-time* guarantee that `max` is initialized at `console.log` (even though the variable `numbers` is a constant, but this would require extensive parsing ... ) - the common solution in other compiled languages is, to assign an initial value, like `let max = 0;`

Comment: Could a work-around be to initialize `max` to `-Infinity`?

Comment: Why don't just initialize `max`?

Comment: `const max = Math.max(...numbers);` or `const max = numbers.reduce((acc, v) => Math.max(acc, v), -Infinity);` would avoid this entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize max by `let max: number = numbers[0];`. That should stop flow from complaining.

Comment: And then what happens if numbers is `[-17, -42, -5]` ?

Comment: Fair point, I'm updating the answer since no initial parameters were supplied.

Comment: That still could have an issue.  What if `numbers` is empty?  A better default might be `-Infinity`.

Comment: Eh...his `!b` should handle that since if numbers is empty, b will simply be undefined. Thus his `if` will still work

Comment: The `max` snippet is deliberately contrived, I wasn't really looking for a way to get it to pass type checking. I'm more looking for a general way to redeclare something, i.e. to tell Flow what something's type is _now_, after modification by some code that Flow can't parse for whatever reason. Flow tries to infer things by analysing my code, and does a good job of it, but there are [fundamental limitations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) to that, so I expected there would be some way to manually (re)declare something in the event that automatic type inference missed something.

Comment: But have the answer anyway

Comment: In response to that then, I have not figured out a way to force flow to infer. If you do, please update it here as another answer, since that should be saved as valuable information. Since flow is essentially a type of compiler and uses ASTs and the like to review your code, I don't believe this exists, unless Facebook wrote it in somehow, but it's not in the docs from what I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

You can also rewrite your code in a less mutable way:

```
const numbers = [5, 3, 22, 2, 6];

const max = numbers.reduce((max, item) => item > max ? item : max,
  Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);

console.log(max + 1);
```

This avoids any kind of mutation, making the life easier for Flow (and probably for humans too :) )